# Divisiones en consulta a tabla

Tags: mysql, highcharts

Estoy comenzando con `MySQL` y `Highcharts`, para mostrar gráficas de algunos sensores.

Lo primero que hago es una *consulta* para guardar los datos en un `array`. Lo hago así:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "", ""); 

if (!$con) 
{ 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    echo $row['Time'] . "\t" . $row['Probe1']. "\n"; 
} 

mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

El caso es que necesito que los datos de la columna `Probe1` se dividan entre 10 (porque el programa me los envía sin decimales). He intentado varias maneras, pero no lo consigo (como hacer una consulta propia dentro de `$row`). Creo que me he complicado la vida y seguro que es algo mucho más sencillo. ¿Podéis echarme una mano?

Comment: Según lo que entiendo, necesitas dividir `$row['Probe1']` entre 10? ¿eso es todo?

Comment: @Jorius si gustas puedes colocarlo como respuesta. Alex, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sí, @Jorius, eso mismo es: dividir el valor que recojo de Probe1 entre 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo único que buscas es dividir el campo, basta con que añadas la división en el momento del uso

```
    <?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "", ""); 

if (!$con) 
{ 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    echo $row['Time'] . "\t" . ($row['Probe1']/10). "\n"; 
} 

mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Aunque la manera correcta sería no hacer un select * para sacar dos campos y hacerlo mejor de la siguiente manera

```
 <?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "", ""); 

if (!$con) 
{ 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Time,(Probe1/10) as Probe1 FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    echo $row['Time'] . "\t" . $row['Probe1']. "\n"; 
} 

mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Comment: Muy buen aporte, Fernando. Lo solucioné con esto: $myquery = "(SELECT `Time`, ROUND(((Probe1)/10),2) Probe1
                FROM table2 ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 60) ORDER BY Time ASC"; Tenías razón, mejor ser preciso.